# bash variable part of path

Tags: bash, shell, permission-denied

I apologize if this question has been answered before. The search terms I could come up with were just too generic to be useful.

In a bash script, I want a parameter to be part of a path. The script says:

```
P=$1
sudo cp ~/work/niagara-root.1/build/$P/linux/vmlinux.64 /tftpboot/
```

I am invoking it with:

```
sh ~/.cpftp.sh TAF-2948-im
```

And I am getting the following error:

```
/home/meirs/.cpftp.sh: 5: /home/meirs/.cpftp.sh: /home/meirs: Permission denied
```

Just to clarify: the script itself has execute permission.

Now when I do it manually at the shell prompt, namely:

```
P=TAF-2948-im
cp ~/work/niagara-root.1/build/$P/linux/vmlinux.64 /tftpboot/
```

It works without a hitch.

What am I missing?

Thank you, one and all

Meir Shani

Comment: update your question with the output of `/bin/ls -ld /home/meirs`. Good luck.

Comment: Please show us the complete script.